# auto click JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery

i need a java script code which would make my website or user's browser think that the user has clicked anywhere on the website even if the user hasn't done it can someone create it for me
Apologies for my bad english
And thanks a lot for having a look at my question
Have a good day

Comment: [```document.querySelector('.some-element').click()```](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/click)

Comment: can you please explain it?

Comment: He is selecting an element on the page with the method querySelector(), as a paramenter of query selector you have to use a css selector to find any element on your page, then he is calling the click method on that element, which clicks the element.